# trouble with Tkinter tags

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to make a functioning "undo" button for a sketchpad on a Tkinter canvas, and have been having some problems. Here's code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

class Write:
    def __init__(self):
        self.write_canvas = Canvas(mainframe, width=500, height=500, background='black')
        self.write_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.save_posn)
        self.write_canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.increase_tag)
        self.write_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
        self.undo_btn = ttk.Button(self.write_subframe, text='Undo', command=self.undo)
        self.tag_num = 0
        self.undo_lst = []

    def grid(self):
        self.write_canvas.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W))
        self.undo_btn.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)

    def save_posn(self, event):
        self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y

    def draw_line(self, event):
        self.write_canvas.create_line((self.x, self.y, event.x, event.y),
                                      tags=str(self.tag_num))
        self.save_posn(event=event)

    def undo(self):
        to_undo = self.undo_lst[-1]
        self.write_canvas.delete(to_undo)
        self.undo_lst.remove(to_undo)

    def increase_tag(self, event):
        self.undo_lst.append(str(self.tag_num))
        self.tag_num += 1

Write().grid()
root.mainloop()
```

So the idea was that each line drawn would be assigned a tag number, and that tag number would be the same for each item in a given stroke, this way the undo button would delete all items within that stroke instead of one line at a time. This is managed by the `increase_tag` method; whenever left click is released, the tag number increases and the next stroke will have a different tag number. When the undo button is pressed, `undo` method is called, and it should take the last tag in `self.undo_lst` (which should correspond with the last set of items drawn) and delete every item with that corresponding tag. This is how I intended it to work, but I just can't get it to work like that. I really don't get why. I confirmed that each item being drawn has the tag that was intended for it, I tried to use `find_withtags()` method as well. That didn't work either. If anyone could help me out with this, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Canvas tags cannot be entirely numeric; such a value would be interpreted as an item ID rather than a tag.  Use something like `"T" + str(self.tag_num)` instead.

Comment: That was it, thank you! I figured that converting that int value to a string would alleviate that issue but evidently not. Thanks again!

Comment: @jasonharper You should add an answer based on your comment so that this doesn't keep popping up in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom canvas tags can't be numeric because they clash with canvas item ids. This is from the canonical documentation:

*"Each item may also have any number of tags associated with it. A tag is just a string of characters, and it may take any form **except that of an integer**. For example, “x123” is OK but “123” is not."*

The simple solution is to add a character to the start of your tags. For example:

```
def increase_tag(self, event):
    self.undo_lst.append(f"tag{self.tag_num}")
    self.tag_num += 1
```

You'll also need to make a similar change when you add the items:

```
def draw_line(self, event):
    self.write_canvas.create_line((self.x, self.y, event.x, event.y),
                                  tags=f"tag{self.tag_num}", fill="red")
    self.save_posn(event=event)
```

Comment: For future reference, can a tag name start with a number eg. `123x`?

Comment: @TheLizzard: I included the relevant information in the answer: _"it may take any form except that of an integer"_. 123x isn't an integer so it's OK.